# Dynamic set increment time by 15 minutes

Tags: php, date, strtotime

I have trouble to increment time by 15 minutes to end time.

I tried `date("H:i:s", strtotime('+15 minutes', strtotime($startTime)));`.
But it is not dynamic.

Here i have starttime and endtime.

```
$startTime = '09:00:00';
$endTime = '11:00:00';
```

And want to output like,

`09:00:00`
`09:15:00`
`09:30:00`
`09:45:00`
`10:00:00`
`10:15:00`
`10:30:00`
`10:45:00`

Thanks.

Comment: You can accept any answer, but please tell me why accept later answer and not my answer?

Comment: Yes your answer is also right. But as you know all answer is order by descending so just i take first and go further.

Comment: Ok, thanks. But it's fairly to accept earlier correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try below code

```
$startTime='09:00:00';
$endTime='11:00:00';
$Times=array();
$interval=15;

while(strtotime($startTime) < strtotime($endTime))
{   
    $Times[]=$startTime;
    $startTime=strtotime("+".$interval." minutes",strtotime($startTime));
    $startTime=date('h:i:s',$startTime);    
}
```

Output

```
Array
(
   [0] => 09:00:00
   [1] => 09:15:00
   [2] => 09:30:00
   [3] => 09:45:00
   [4] => 10:00:00
   [5] => 10:15:00
   [6] => 10:30:00
   [7] => 10:45:00
)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think using do...while you can do this

use this code:

```
$startTime = '09:00:00';
$endTime = '11:00:00';
$inc = "";
do {
    $inc = date("H:i:s", strtotime('+15 minutes', strtotime($startTime)));
    $startTime = $inc;
    echo $inc."   ";
}while($inc < $endTime);
```

**output:**

09:15:00 09:30:00 09:45:00 10:00:00 10:15:00 10:30:00 10:45:00 11:00:00

Answer (score 1):

You can use following codes:

```
<?php

$startTime = '09:00:00';
$endTime = '11:00:00';

$times = array();
$last_inc = $startTime;
while($last_inc < $endTime) {
    $times[] = $last_inc;
    $last_inc = date("H:i:s", strtotime("+15 minutes $last_inc"));
}

print_r($times);
```

Ouput:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 09:00:00
    [1] => 09:15:00
    [2] => 09:30:00
    [3] => 09:45:00
    [4] => 10:00:00
    [5] => 10:15:00
    [6] => 10:30:00
    [7] => 10:45:00
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to loop over time to generate data you want

```
$startTime = '09:00:00';
$endTime = '11:00:00';
$new_Time = $startTime;
while($new_Time < $endTime){
    $new_Time = date("H:i:s", strtotime('+15 minutes', strtotime($new_Time)));
    echo $new_Time;
    echo "<br>";
}
```

o/p:

```
09:15:00
09:30:00
09:45:00
10:00:00
10:15:00
10:30:00
10:45:00
11:00:00
```